# Decode url with space in it from decodable model

Tags: swift, decodable

I have the following structure and response parsing fails because url (`https://example.url.com/test a`) has a space in it. How can I escape it with %20 value in deserialization layer and keep it as URL type?

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let url: URL

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.url = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self).decode(URL.self, forKey: .url)
    }
}

let string = "{\"url\":\"https://example.url.com/test a\"}"
let responseModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: string.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(responseModel?.url)
```

Comment: Needless to say, spaces are not permitted in URLs. While you can fix it after decoding like others suggested, the right solution is to make sure your source had valid URLs. It’s going to be better to fix the source, if possible, rather than cleaning it up after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob has already mentioned it would be better to fix the issue at the backend instead of fixing the decoding part. If you can not fix it at the server side you can decote your url as a string, percent escape it and then use the resulting string to initialize your url property:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let url: URL
}
```

---

```
extension Response {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let string = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .url)
        guard
            let percentEncoded = string
                .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
            let url = URL(string: percentEncoded)
        else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .url,
                                                   in: container,
                debugDescription: "Invalid url string: \(string)")
        }
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let jsonString = #"{"url":"https://example.url.com/test a"}"#
do {
    let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(responseModel.url)
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

This will print

> https://example.url.com/test%20a

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible with a `JSONDecoder` customisation or in the serialization layer as you've mentioned in the post. The best you can achieve would be to do this:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let urlString: String

    var url: URL {
        URL(string: urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))!
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case urlString = "url"
    }
}
```

Note: You don't need `init(decoder:)` if you don't have a custom implementation. Also don't need the `CodingKeys` enum if the property names are the same as the string keys (In your case `url` key is redundant).

Comment: Note: When conforming to `Decodable` (not the same as Codable) you NEED to provide CodingKeys implementation no matter if the property names are the same or not.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot decode `url` as an URL, as in `decode(URL.self...`), because it is *not* an URL. Change your `url` property to String, decode this value as `String.self`, and deal with turning the String into a URL *later* in the process.